# Unable to resize Ubuntu VM with VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, gparted

I've gone through some of the similar questions asked, but none seem to quite solve my problem.

I have a VirtualBox 4.2 install on Ubuntu 12.04 (x64) as host, with Ubuntu 12.04 Server (x64) as guest. I misjudged initial storage needs and wish to resize my .vdi disk.

I tried the following:

`vboxmanage modifyhd file.vdi -31744`

To resize my vdi disk to 31GB, and it gave me a successful completion message. Virtualbox notes the file as having a virtual size of 31GB, actual size 4.23.

I've tried using both GParted live and Ubuntu LiveCD with GParted, but the result is the same: the new space simple does not appear. GParted can still only find one disk /dev/sda, which is the same size before I tried resizing it with vboxmanage. Obviously, this means I cannot repartition.

Has anyone run into this issue before? I would greatly appreciate some insight.

PS. The filesystem is ext4.

**Edit**: I just noticed that my actual .vdi file has not grown in size. I would have thought that it would. Might be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second bigger disk, use gparted to copy the contents of the old disk to the new one, then delete the old one.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to clone over the disk if at all possible, unfortunately.